# I can't find an ionic 2 plugin popup

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In Ionic 2 i can't find a nice popup plugin, i found ionic super popup but it not work with Ionic 2, what plugin do you advise me to use ?

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but are you looking for `alerts`?

See this link: [Alert Ionic 2 Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

presentAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Low battery',
    subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });
  alert.present();
}
```